# ddrescue a drive

Tags: data-recovery, corruption, ddrescue, forensics

**Background:**

I have attempted to rescue a drive which seems to have corruptions using the following commands:

```
ddrescue --no-split /dev/hda1 imagefile logfile 

ddrescue --direct --retry-passes=3 /dev/hda1 imagefile logfile 

ddrescue --direct --retrim --retry-passes=3 /dev/hda1 imagefile logfile
```

This leaves me with an errsize of 90000 B.  How do I extract the remaining 90000 B?

I have attempted to re-run the 2nd and 3rd commands, and the errsize reduces each time by around 100 B.  It will take forever if I try the re-run approach.  Is there a different variation of the commands I could try which might speed it up?

---

**Other possible relevant details:**

```
ddrescue -v (1.19)

uname -r (4.4.0-64-generic)
```

---

**Question:**

How do I speed up the time it is taking to reduce the errsize, as re-running the above commands is reducing the errsize excruciatingly slowly?

Comment: Looks like you have done all you can do to rescue the data from the drive. As you stated in the question, _it seems to have corruptions_. Apparently the remaining 90KiB is inside the corrupted areas, and you've rescued all you can. Now you have to verify the integrity of everything you "rescued" to see how much of it was actually recovered, and what was damaged but looked good to `ddrescue`. The little pieces you are getting, ~100B/pass, are probably not reliable anyway IMHO.

Comment: It's 90kb anyway. Seriously, you will probably end up with **one** broken file out of the whole file system assuming those 90kb are placed where an allocated file is. Is this worth the effort? It might be if that file is absolutely mission critical, but otherwise... just let it be. Your time alone is more precious than 90kb of data.